# Chi-Squared 2df = 2nλ/λˆ MGF Needed?

Tags: exponential-function, moment-generating-functions, chi-squared

Question:
Assume that $T_i (i = 1, ..., n)$ are independently identically distributed with exponential distribution with hazard $\lambda$. Assuming there is no censoring, prove that:

$$\frac{2nλ}{\hat \lambda} ∼ χ^2_{2n} $$ where $\hat \lambda$ is the MLE of $\lambda$.

Notes(adding all I can to help):

$$\hat \lambda = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n T_i}$$

I know this has something to do with the moment generating function, but I just can't get it to come out right.

Also, I believe that(if I remember correctly):

MGF of $\sum_{i=1}^n T_i$ is the same as MGF of $T_i$ raised to the $n^{\text{th}}$ power.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!!!!

Here's the answer in case anyone was interested:

[image]

Things I needed to know:

Expoential distribution is scalar.
MGF of a sum of $n$ identical distributions is the MGF of one to the $n^{\text{th}}$ power.

Comment: A few minor comments. First, note that $M_W(t) = \frac{1}{1-2t}$ and not $\frac{1}{2t-1}$, and that this is valid for $t<\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, $M_S(t) = (1-2t)^{-n}$ for $t<\frac{1}{2}$, which is indeed the moment generating function of a $\chi^2$ distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: I'll fix this when I get home tonight, so people don't make the same mistake.